# I want to import XML data to sqlite database and save it in table . After saving i want to use it in my application

Tags: android

The xml file is saved into my  D drive. I want to import all data from this xml and save in sqlite without putting it into resource folder of my project.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to Parse your xml

read data as per your requirement

Insert it into database at a time.

Then you can user for further use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026656/i-want-to-import-xml-data-to-sqlite-databas-and-save-it-in-table-after-saving/10026954#10026954   Can you provide some code sample

Comment: Foe parsing: [link](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/) here[link]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026656/i-want-to-import-xml-data-to-sqlite-database-and-save-it-in-table-after-saving   thanks for link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026656/i-want-to-import-xml-data-to-sqlite-database-and-save-it-in-table-after-saving  parsing is done how to save this data in sqlite help....pls..

Comment: http://marakana.com/static/tutorials/SQLDemo.zip

see this tutorial..

you can mark this and as correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026656/i-want-to-import-xml-data-to-sqlite-database-and-save-it-in-table-after-saving Anyone have sample source code for inserting data in sqlite by xml parsing.pls.. provide me...